# Opencv solvepnp not returning the center of the object

Tags: python, opencv

I'm learning opencv and I need to find the distance and angle from the camera to a ball in a picture. My steps so far to do this are:

1. Get a contour surrounding the ball
2. Use `minEnclosingCircle` to turn the contour into a perfect circle
3. Use `solvePnP` with 5 points on the circle to find the actual location of the ball

The issue I'm having is that `tvec[0][0]`, the x distance from the center of the camera returned from `solvePnP`, is taken from the leftmost point on the circle, not the center of the circle. This causes my angle calculations to get the angle between the center of the camera and the leftmost point of the ball, instead of the center of the ball.

The code that runs the calculations on the contour is below:

```py
def process_circle_cnt(cnt):
    obj_p = np.array([
        [5.5, 5.5, 0],
        [0, 5.5, 0],
        [11, 5.5, 0],
        [5.5, 0, 0],
        [5.5, 11, 0]
    ])

    (x, y), radius = cv.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
    img_p = np.array([
        (x, y),
        (x - radius, y),
        (x + radius, y),
        (x, y - radius),
        (x, y + radius)
    ])

    _, rvec, tvec = cv.solvepnp(obj_p, img_p, camera_matrix, dist_matrix)
    x = tvec[0][0]
    z = tvec[2][0]
    distance = math.sqrt(x**2 + z**2)
    angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(x, z))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: just change `cx` and `cy` in camera_matrix to -5.5, e.g. 
`camera_matrix[0:2,2] = -5.5`

Answer (score 0):

You can measure the distance between the left-most point (where the translation vector falls) and the center of the circle, then apply the Pythagorean theorem to calculate the distance from camera center to circle center.

Comment: Of course this works only if the angle between distance vector and circle plane is 90°. Otherwise you can apply the cosine rule
`a^2 = b^2 + c^2 − 2*b*c*cos(A)`
where b and c are the sides of the triangle that you know and A is the angle between them.